# underscore/lodash unique by multiple properties

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, unique, lodash

I have an array of objects with duplicates and I'm trying to get a unique listing, where uniqueness is defined by a subset of the properties of the object. For example,

```
{a:"1",b:"1",c:"2"}
```

And I want to ignore `c` in the uniqueness comparison.

I can do something like

```
_.uniq(myArray,function(element) { return element.a + "_" + element+b});
```

I was hoping I could do

```
_.uniq(myArray,function(element) { return {a:element.a, b:element.b} });
```

But that doesn't work. Is there something like that I can do, or do I need to create a comparable representation of the object if I'm comparing multiple properties?

Comment: And why are you trying to do the second attempt? The first one is working, right?

Comment: Yes the first is working but it feels a bit hacky to have to do the string concatenation. Trying to understand if there's a more natural way to do this.

Comment: objects are always unique, so you need to compare by individual property values, not by whole objects. using a string compare can work with certain data but not others, for example: with numerical strings like shown, you risk colliding {a:"1"} with {a:1}.s

Comment: _.uniq([{a:"1",b:"1",c:"2"},{a:"1",b:"2",c:"2"},{a:"1",b:"1",c:"2"}], JSON.stringify); JSON order is not guaranteed, but i can't see why this wouldn't work within a single browser.

Comment: In my particular case, I'm only comparing strings. @dandavis I don't want to compare all of the attributes, only a subset of them

Comment: @dandavis I think it would be better to pack the properties into arrays before JSONifying them. Or write your own version of `_.uniq` that uses [`_.isEqual`](http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual) instead of `===`.

Comment: @JeffStorey you want to use `_unique` strictly, or you want to do a more functional solution? like creating a comparator function and combine `reduce/find` or combile `filter/find`?

Answer (score 52):

Use Lodash's [`uniqWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/#uniqWith) method:

#### `_.uniqWith(array, [comparator])`

> This method is like `_.uniq` except that it accepts `comparator` which is invoked to compare elements of `array`. The order of result values is determined by the order they occur in the array. The comparator is invoked with two arguments: *(arrVal, othVal)*.

When the `comparator` returns `true`, the items are considered duplicates and only the first occurrence will be included in the new array.

---

**Example:** 
I have a list of locations with `latitude` and `longitude` coordinates -- some of which are identical -- and I want to see the list of locations with unique coordinates:

```js
const locations = [
  {
    name: "Office 1",
    latitude: -30,
    longitude: -30
  },
  {
    name: "Office 2",
    latitude: -30,
    longitude: 10
  },
  {
    name: "Office 3",
    latitude: -30,
    longitude: 10
  }
];

const uniqueLocations = _.uniqWith(
  locations,
  (locationA, locationB) =>
    locationA.latitude === locationB.latitude &&
    locationA.longitude === locationB.longitude
);

// Result has Office 1 and Office 2
```

Comment: This should be the answer

Comment: This works but needs a Return inside the function

Comment: @Franco the arrow function is using an implicit `return`. [Read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#function_body)

Comment: What's about complexity?
i'm not sure but presumably `uniqWIth` has O(n^2) but `uniqBy` has O(n)

Comment: @StanislauListratsenka I think they're two different tools for two different purposes. If all you need is `uniqBy`, I'd use that. In my opinion, this use case prefers `uniqWith`.

I'm not sure about the complexity. At first glance, it seems like it would be 2N, not n^2, which is the same as the solutions that use `uniqBy`. But I'm not 100% sure. Let me know if you discover anything in the source code.

Answer (score 43):

There doesn't seem to be a straightforward way to do this, unfortunately. Short of writing your own function for this, you'll need to return something that can be directly compared for equality (as in your first example).

One method would be to just `.join()` the properties you need:

```
_.uniqBy(myArray, function(elem) { return [elem.a, elem.b].join(); });
```

Alternatively, you can use [`_.pick`](https://lodash.com/docs#pick) or [`_.omit`](https://lodash.com/docs#omit) to remove whatever you don't need. From there, you could use `_.values` with a `.join()`, or even just `JSON.stringify`:

```
_.uniqBy(myArray, function(elem) {
    return JSON.stringify(_.pick(elem, ['a', 'b']));
});
```

Keep in mind that objects are not deterministic as far as property order goes, so you may want to just stick to the explicit array approach.

P.S. Replace `uniqBy` with `uniq` for **Lodash < 4**

Comment: Using `join('')` is full of holes (such as `[1,23]` and `[12,3]`).

Comment: @muistooshort: Good point - I suppose the standard comma-delimited join would be better.

Comment: @voithos: but what if the data contains a comma? or if a number is/isnt quoted?

Comment: @dandavis: I suppose you could do `JSON.stringify` on the array, instead of using `join`. Really, though, it would be easier to just rewrite `uniq` to take into consideration multiple properties.

Comment: lodash 4 comes with `_.uniqWith(myArray, _.isEqual)`

Comment: @nilspetersohn Thanks, works for me. But out of curiosity, what does the regular `.uniq` use, if not `_.isEqual`?

Comment: @vinhboy it uses [SameValueZero](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-samevaluezero). Ref. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniq Ref. https://lodash.com/docs/3.10.1#uniq

Answer (score 10):

Here there's the correct answer

[javascript - lodash - create a unique list based on multiple attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37316181/javascript-lodash-create-a-unique-list-based-on-multiple-attributes?rq=1).

FYI  `var result = _.uniqBy(list, v => [v.id, v.sequence].join());`

Answer (score 2):

late to the party but I found this in lodash docs.

```
var objects = [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }, { 'x': 2, 'y': 1 }, { 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }];
 
_.uniqWith(objects, _.isEqual);
// => [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }, { 'x': 2, 'y': 1 }]
```

Comment: This is the most elegant solution imo. This should be marked as the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

I do think that the join() approach is still the simplest. Despite concerns raised in the previous solution, I think choosing the right separator is the key to avoiding the identified pitfalls (with different value sets returning the same joined value). Keep in mind, the separator need not be a single character, it can be any string that you are confident will not occur naturally in the data itself. I do this all the time and am fond of using '~!$~' as my separator. It can also include special characters like \t\r\n etc.

If the data contained is truly that unpredictable, perhaps the max length is known and you could simply pad each element to its max length before joining.

Answer (score 1):

There is a hint in @voithos and @Danail combined answer. How I solved this was to add a unique key on the objects in my array.

Starting Sample Data

```
const animalArray = [
  { a: 4, b: 'cat', d: 'generic' },
  { a: 5, b: 'cat', d: 'generic' },
  { a: 4, b: 'dog', d: 'generic' },
  { a: 4, b: 'cat', d: 'generic' },
];
```

In the example above, I want the array to be unique by `a` and `b` but right now I have two objects that have `a: 4` and `b: 'cat'`. By combining a + b into a string I can get a unique key to check by.

```
{ a: 4, b: 'cat', d: 'generic', id: `${a}-${b}` }. // id is now '4-cat'
```

**Note:** You obviously need to map over the data or do this during creation of the object as you cannot reference properties of an object within the same object.

Now the comparison is simple...

```
_.uniqBy(animalArray, 'id');
```

The resulting array will be length of 3 it will have removed the last duplicate.