# Remove repeated occurance from an array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have a requirement to remove repeated objects from an array based on certain condition check 
If any of the object with same "connector", "address", "type" values in this array i need remove that object.

```
array =  [{
        connector : 'smtp',
        name : 'john',
        address : 'john@gmail.com',
        type : 'cc'
    }, {
        connector : 'smtp',
        name : 'john',
        address : 'john@gmail.com',
        type : 'cc'
    }, {
        connector : 'gtp',
        name : 'mark',
        address : 'mark@gmail.com',
        type : 'cc'
    }, {
        connector : 'ftp',
        name : 'wiki',
        address : 'wiki@gmail.com',
        type : 'bcc'
    },
    {
        connector : 'smtp',
        name : 'wiki',
        address : 'wiki@gmail.com',
        type : 'cc'
    }
 ]
```

I need the output like the following way

```
output = [{
        connector : 'smtp',
        name : 'john',
        address : 'john@gmail.com',
        type : 'cc'
    },{
        connector : 'gtp',
        name : 'mark',
        address : 'mark@gmail.com',
        type : 'cc'
    }, {
        connector : 'ftp',
        name : 'wiki',
        address : 'wiki@gmail.com',
        type : 'bcc'
    },
    {
        connector : 'smtp',
        name : 'wiki',
        address : 'wiki@gmail.com',
        type : 'cc'
    }
 ]
```

Sorry i tried some repeated foreach looping but ended up no where. Could you help me to find any efficient way of doing the same.

Comment: Add the code you've tried

Comment: try looking into underscore.js library. they have duplicate filter function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with the help of underscore uniq.

```
array =  [{
        connector : 'smtp',
        name : 'john',
        address : 'john@gmail.com',
        type : 'cc'
    }, {
        connector : 'smtp',
        name : 'john',
        address : 'john@gmail.com',
        type : 'cc'
    }, {
        connector : 'gtp',
        name : 'mark',
        address : 'mark@gmail.com',
        type : 'cc'
    }, {
        connector : 'ftp',
        name : 'wiki',
        address : 'wiki@gmail.com',
        type : 'bcc'
    },
    {
        connector : 'smtp',
        name : 'wiki',
        address : 'wiki@gmail.com',
        type : 'cc'
    }
 ]
 //generating a string of keys you wish to compare which forms the criteria for uniqueness
 add = _.uniq(array, function(a){ return a.connector + "-" + a.address + "-" + a.type;})

 console.log(add)
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/xysayfan/)

Comment: `uniqBy` can also be used. `_.uniqBy(array, obj => obj.connector + '-' + obj.address + '-' + obj.type);`

Comment: `JSON.stringify` is improve solution, i hope

Comment: @Tushar are you sure about the uniqBy its not there in the doc http://underscorejs.org/

Comment: @Cyril It is in Lodash

Comment: Use Lodash's [`uniqWith`](https://lodash.com/docs#uniqWith) explained in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52525557/6172657) to avoid comparing Strings.

Comment: Ok lodash is also one way of doing it..set can be another way of doing the same...what I answered is another way of doing it.