# How to get unique JSON array by JSON value?

Tags: javascript, json, unique

I have one JSON array. I need a unique array. I have tried all possible things using .map(), .filter().  but no success.

Also, I have applied alternatives but it does not work for me. such as

[How to get distinct values from an array of objects in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125920/how-to-get-distinct-values-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

[How to make a JSON array unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826302/how-to-make-a-json-array-unique)

```
var slots = [
    {
        id: 1239,
        slot1: "08:00:00-16:00:00",
        slot2: null,
        slot3: null,
        slot4: null,
        slot5: null,
        slot6: null,
        slot7: null,
        slot8: null,
        slot9: null,
        slot10: null,
        slot11: null,
        slot12: null,
        slot13: null,
        slot14: null,
        slot15: null,
        slot16: null,
        slot17: null,
        slot18: null,
        slot19: null,
        slot20: null,
        slots_end: "2021-07-06T16:00:00+03:00",
        slots_start: "2021-07-06T08:00:00+03:00",
    },
    {
        id: 1240,
        slot1: "09:00:00-18:00:00",
        slot2: null,
        slot3: null,
        slot4: null,
        slot5: null,
        slot6: null,
        slot7: null,
        slot8: null,
        slot9: null,
        slot10: null,
        slot11: null,
        slot12: null,
        slot13: null,
        slot14: null,
        slot15: null,
        slot16: null,
        slot17: null,
        slot18: null,
        slot19: null,
        slot20: null,
        slots_end: "2021-07-06T18:00:00+03:00",
        slots_start: "2021-07-06T09:00:00+03:00",
    },
    {
        id: 1241,
        slot1: "09:00:00-18:00:00",
        slot2: null,
        slot3: null,
        slot4: null,
        slot5: null,
        slot6: null,
        slot7: null,
        slot8: null,
        slot9: null,
        slot10: null,
        slot11: null,
        slot12: null,
        slot13: null,
        slot14: null,
        slot15: null,
        slot16: null,
        slot17: null,
        slot18: null,
        slot19: null,
        slot20: null,
        slots_end: "2021-07-06T18:00:00+03:00",
        slots_start: "2021-07-06T09:00:00+03:00",
    },
]
```

As a result, should be...

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: unique json array? what u r looking for..

Comment: how you are deciding the uniqueness of array ? comparing all the array values or some specific keys ?

Comment: @Muhammad Atif Akram, the keys will same, I want a unique Object by value.

Comment: question is unclear.

Comment: @Negi Rox, My question is, I have a JSON array. as I have added in the question.
So, I need a unique JSON object in the array.

Comment: FYI there's no JSON in this question.  See [What are the differences between JSON and JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975859/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-javascript-object)

Comment: Your "as a result" screenshot looks to be *exactly* the same as your source array.  What am I missing from the fuzzy screenshot?

Comment: Just mention on what base you will decide the uniqueness of array . If you want to compare all the properties then each object will be unique since each object has unique id. So decide first which properties you need to compare to get the unique array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove similar objects from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36909866/remove-similar-objects-from-array)

Comment: @MiteshRathod I'm not sure what you want but try: let something = new Set([...slots]);